# Use plugin config as paramater in services.yml

Tags: dependency-injection, plugins, shopware6

The documentation only shows that you can [pass the SystemConfigService as a parameter](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/use-plugin-configuration#reading-the-configuration) to another service.

Is there also the possibility to pass directly the value from the plugin configuration?

Background of the question: I would like to initialize directly an instance of an external component. But this expects fixed arguments as strings. Alternatively, one would otherwise have to write some kind of factory.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, it's possible to do. I have not done this directly myself, but 99% confident that it will work. You may need to play around with it a little.

In the services.xml you can use symfony expressions.

```xml
<argument type="expression">service('Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService').get('SwagBasicExample.config.example')</argument>
```

You may need to find the alias name for the `Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService` class instead. Also check the Symfony documentation, you can do a lot more with this!

I myself passed an array as an argument, but used a custom class as a config getter like so:

```xml
<argument type="expression">
                    {
                    "shop_is_active": service('config_bridge').get('isActive'),
                    "customer_number": service('config_bridge').get('customerNumber'),
                    "shop_number": service('config_bridge').get('shopNumber'),
                    "apikey": service('config_bridge').get('apiKey')
                    }
</argument>
```

---

Not strictly necessary as Shopware already requires it, but always a good practice to add the requirement to your plugin composer file:

```json
  "require": {
    ...,
    "symfony/expression-language": "~5.3.0|~5.4.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

As of today it's not possible to inject specific `system_config` values in services.